# Selected check box value using css

Tags: jquery, css

I have a `css`

```
input[type=checkbox]:not(old) + label > span, input[type=radio ]:not(old) + label > span {
    display : inline-block;
    width : 30px;
    height : 30px;
    margin : 0.25em 0.5em 0.25em 0.25em;
    border-radius : 0.25em;
    background : #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: absolute;
}
```

I wanted to get the checked checkbox value with the following piece of code :

```
$("input[name=email]:not(old)+ label").click(function() {
    console.log($("input[name=email]:not(old)").is(':checked')); // getting false                                 
})
```

HTML

```
<input name="gender" type="radio" value="Female">
<label for="gender">
    <span><span></span></span>
    <p>Female</p>
</label>
```

empty spans are for displaying the selected checkbox in the bellow style
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

**Note:** I have already seen many post how to check selected checkbox using jquery and javascript in SO but none of them are near to my requirement.

Comment: What is `old` in `:not(old)`?

Comment: @Aziz added my html snippet too

Comment: @Satpal those are css style attributes

Comment: care to explain the empty spans?

Comment: @Aziz I have updated my question with the css image

Comment: hello, down voter could you please extend your cause of downvote, so I can correct my question. Feel free to add a comment too.

Comment: OK I get it now, could you please create a jsfiddle demo so we could see the changes and understand it more?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101501/discussion-between-rockstar-and-aziz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is your code update:

```
$("input").click(function() {
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

this can used if you want to get checkbox/radio value or if you want to get label's paragraph value than use:

```
  $("input").click(function() {
    console.log($(this).next('label').children('p').text());                                
   });
```

here is the working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kuactq01/